# Docker build jar file with gradle takes too long

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I have this `Dockerfile` where I want to build a spring boot project with gradle then run it  but the build takes up to 100 seconds to finish but in my local machine it builds fast. I'm sure it's a caching issue but I don't know how to speed it up and I'm kind of new to Docker

```
FROM gradle:7.5.1-jdk11-alpine AS build

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src

WORKDIR /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle clean build --no-daemon


FROM openjdk:11.0.11-jre-slim-buster

EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir /app

COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/demo.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/demo.jar"]
```

Comment: "As such, a valid Dockerfile must start with a FROM instruction." - I don't see it, where's the initial FROM statement?

Comment: @ChristophDahlen sorry problem with formatting. I've updated my question

Comment: Depending on the OS and how you run Docker, it might have restrictions on resources. i.e. Docker Desktop for Mac will set it quite low but can be changed in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine you will have a local cache of various things (node/npm, gradle, maven, etc.) that means those repeated tasks will be faster. However on a docker image build essentially you are starting with a blank/clean cache in the base image all the time and so it will need to pull everything anew.

You could look to find where the caches are stored and perhaps mount a volume there to allow a cache to persist between image builds if you really wanted to speed things up, but depending on how often you need to rebuild the image that may or may not add much value.

Answer (score 0):

RUN gradle --no-daemon clean bootJar and
try to use **openjdk:11.0.11-jre-slim** it's smaller than **openjdk:11.0.11-jre-slim-buster**

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Building docker image for maven/gradle can be slow, somehow https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib help the process Dockerize java apps much-much faster.

[For Spring-boot](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/examples/spring-boot)

I know it's different point of view from `Dockerfile` solution, but after using this tools, never focus on Dockerfile anymore but docker-compose instead (for deployment concern).